# Start heading 1 of existing docx in new page with python-docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

In an existing word document, I want to start all the headings 1 beginning from the new page using #python-docx. I have tried the following code as below:

```
from docx import *

document=Document("document location")

sections=document.sections

for section in sections:

   document.add_page_break()
```

but the code is not working and it is adding additional page breaker where the existing heading 1 starting with new page. Please suggest any solution

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data.

Comment: Hi richardec, It could be any word document with some sections(heading 1) and objective is to start each section from the start of a page.I have created a sample document for example. Please find the link.  [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/15SPaw7MMMxTKioUU1-IOq1--domGjRhW/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103568039304009985232&rtpof=true&sd=true).